# How To Check Multiple Select Whether It's Selected Or Not?

Tags: jquery

I have this simplified HTML structure :

```
<div id="kurir_list">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select disabled class="tarif">
                ...
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select disabled class="tarif">
                ...
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select disabled class="tarif">
                ...
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have this jquery too :

```
$(".tarif").change(function() {
    if (!$(".tarif").is(':disabled')) {
        alert ("hello world");

        if ($(".tarif").val() !== "") {
            alert ("hello earth");
        }
    }
});
```

why "hello earth" never shows up even though all `.tarif` has selected option? how to make validation whether `.tarif` has empty selection or not? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method with `length` property.

```
//Cache elements
var tarif = $(".tarif");

tarif.change(function() {
    //Filter not disabled elements
    var notDisabledTarif = tarif.filter('not(:disabled)');

    //There is atleast 1 element which is not disabled
    if(notDisabledTarif.length){
        alert ("hello world");

        //Filter elements having value
        var elementHavingValue = notDisabledTarif.filter(function(){
            return $(this).val() !== "";
        });

        if (elementHavingValue.length) {
            alert ("hello earth");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: bro, the problem is, I need to check all `.tarif` whether it has disabled or empty value, every time one of `.tarif` is changed. not just current selection. but all of select elements under `#kurir_list`

Comment: @RobertHanson, Just for clarification, You need to check any select element has value and not disabled, right?